# Using Morphia with Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, morphia

The Google Code site of Morphia says it *"works great with Guice, Spring, and other DI frameworks."*

I'm learning Spring at the moment, so i'm just experimenting with connecting these two tools.
I've created a `User` POJO to store user objects with Morphia in MongoDB. I've also created a `UserDAO` class extending `BasicDAO` from Morphia to access objects.

My Spring application context configuration XML looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd"
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop">

      <bean class="java.lang.String" id="mongoDb">
        <constructor-arg value="test"/>
      </bean>

      <bean class="com.google.code.morphia.Morphia" id="morphia" />
      <bean class="com.mongodb.Mongo" id="mongo"/>
      <bean class="hu.inagy.testspring.daos.UserDAO" id="userDao">
        <constructor-arg ref="morphia" index="0" />
        <constructor-arg ref="mongo" index="1" />
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoDb" index="2" />
      </bean>

    </beans>
```

I have a simple main class to test functionality:

```
  public class App 
  {
      public static void main( String[] args )
      {
          ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/app-context.xml");
          UserDAO userDao = (UserDAO) applicationContext.getBean("userDao");

          userDao.deleteByQuery(userDao.createQuery());

          User user = new User();
          user.setName("Test");
          userDao.save(user);

          User ret = userDao.find().get();
          System.out.println("Saved user is: "+ret);
      }
  }
```

This works fine, however i don't know if i did everything as it should be. For example i haven't called `ensureIndexes()` and `ensureCaps()` on the datastore. My code also doesn't have an explicit mapping call for the POJOs on the Morphia object.

Are these done for me automatically or should i do other things to use Morphia correctly with Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use spring but this articles seems to talk about exactly what you need, a hook to do things when you app starts: http://leshazlewood.com/2007/07/30/spring-application-bootstrap-data/

You can do the Datastore.ensureIndexes/Caps() there.

You can also read this thread about using @Autowire and annotations instead of the xml, if you like that stuff.

http://groups.google.com/group/morphia/browse_thread/thread/1013b17963f29468